# How can an activity indicator in a button be positioned a certain distance before the button text

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a requirement to display a standard button which display some text, then when the user clicks on the button the text changes to something else and an activity indicator is displayed in the button.
How can I use constraints to position the activity indicator N points before the text?

Will I have to create a view and put the activity indicator and text in the view, use constraints to set the distance between them, set place the view in the button as opposed to just setting the text directly in the button as you would normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is button's [`titleLabel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623992-titlelabel). So you can position something relative to that easily.